# Omni Channel Presence Status Change

Tags: omnichannel

I have a requirement where I need to change the status of the agent automatically when he accepts the work item in omni channel.

As far as I understand we cannot do it in a standard way and we need to customize.

Comment: It is standard functionality. Are you using snapin chat component? Or you can use button deployment code from chat deployment.

Comment: For live agent it is working. But I am implementing skill based routing in omni channel and we are routing the cases created from Web-to-case and emai-to-case.     For these cases,when agent accepts a work item i need to change the status automatically